# Pass alt-d or ctrl-l in html so that it forces cursor to go to address bar on page load

Tags: javascript, position, cursor

My scanner reads a qr code with a url, I need to force the cursor to the address bar.  I know alt-d or ctrl-l sends the cursor to the browser address bar, how would I accomplish this within html, so that when the page loads, it would be as if the alt-d or ctrl-l combo would be initiated.

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be done. But if it can, it will almost certainly have to be done in Javascript, not HTML.

Comment: I just found this: chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab) {
            chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { 'url': url, 'selected': true });
        });  how do I implement this code?

Comment: Put it in a function that you call from `window.onload`. It's basic Javascript.

Comment: That code you found only works for Chrome Extensions, standard websites won't have access to that API. I think you can't achieve what you want using Javascript/HTML, you might need a plugin...